# how to query with groupBy in jdbctemplate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using jdbctemplate of Spring, and I have the following query:

```
SELECT ?, count(*) as " + counter + " FROM data GROUP BY ?
```

When i'm using

```
List<Map<String, Object>> values = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,columnName, columnName);
```

I get a wrong query results - I get one row with counter of 11 - which is the counter of ALL the rows in the data table. So clearly the groupBy doesn't work correctly.
I debugged the code and saw that the executed query is in fact

```
SELECT 'COLUMN_3', count(*) as COUNTER FROM DATA GROUP BY 'COLUMN_3'
```

So I suspect that the additional apostrophes are what causing the bug.

How can I solve this? (Without using simple String query - I want to use the PreparedStatement so I won't have any SQL Injection problems).

Comment: You can't use placeholder for column or tables names. These information are needed by the database to prepare the execution plan of the query. prepared statement placeholders are for values. If you let the user choose what it wants to select (which is extremely rare), then reject the choice if it's not part of a whitelist of column names.

Comment: It's still weird for me - because the query 'almost' succeeds, all that is left are those apostrophes...But as you are not the only one to say that, I guess I don't have any choice. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't almost work. It selects a constant string 'COLUMN_3' instead of selecting the value of the column_3. Because you can't pass column names as prepared statement parameters. Only values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the sql ? placeholders only in the WHERE clause of Sql PreparedStatements such as 
WHERE bossesname=?

In your case replace the ?s with java variables as in:

```
String columnName = "COLUMN_3";
String counter = "COUNTER";
SELECT " + columnName + ", count(*) as " + counter + " FROM data GROUP BY " + columnName
```

Then use a simplified form of queryForList:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> values = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
```

Comment: Hi, as I said in the question - that causes SQL Injection problems.

Comment: Perhaps I have not understood what you are trying to do, I have edited my answer. Also I don't think this simple statement is in any danger of SQL injection, only the variables in WHERE clauses.

Comment: @mwarren Will  jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql); work? As queryForList(..) specifically looks for the selected column count as 1